# Qt webenginewidgets troubleshoots

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit, qtwebengine, qtwebapp

I'm using Qt Creator 4.10.1 in Windows 7 ( Qt version 5.13.1 (MSVC 2017, 32 bit) ). 
I'm triying to make a navigator app for Windows. 
When I try to use the " webenginewidgets "  in my *.pro file and execute the qmake I have this error " Unknown module in QT : webenginewidgets ". 
I verrified if the " Webkit" is installed in the QT directory, it is. 
some proposed to use the MSVC 2013 at least. I have MSVC 2015 and 2017 installed and do have a VS 2017 installed in my laptop ( but I see an exclamation point beside it in the Tools/Options/kits/QT versions and a message that this compiler can't produce any code for this QT version" , only MSVC 2015 32bits and MINGW work correctlly).

my *.pro file:

```
FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

QT += widgets webenginewidgets

CONFIG += c++11
```

the error I'm getting " Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets "

here are some images to help you to understand:

MainWindow.cpp 
[image]

Qt versions
[image]

[image]

Can any one propose a solution or guide me to find one?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to makes sure you are compiling with MSVC 2017 or MSVC 2019. If you configured Qt with an older Windows compiler, QtWebEngine is just going to be skipped. The reason being that Chromium uses C++14, and only the latest version of VS2017 and up supports that.

Edit: For older versions of Qt like 5.9, MSVC 2015 also compiles QtWebEngine, but MSVC 2013 does not.

Comment: But howw to know witch copiler I'm using since they are all autodetected ( including MSVC 2017 and 2015)? and how can i select the compiler?  I searched in the QT documentation but none of there indications helped me since i staretd to use there IDE only few days ago.

Comment: It depends on what compiler you installed before Qt Creator, or if you have multiple which one you have chosen. You can select which one goes into which kit in the Qt Creator options. Personally I prefer to bulid inside VS command shell, then you just pick the shell from the right VS folder, that has the setup you want.